# Remove ASCII Question Mark

Tags: java, ascii

I have the following String passed from another application.

```
2&#65533;4&#65533;9&#65533;
```

(2�4�9�)

I would like to remove question mark ascii characters from the above string.

How could I do this?

Comment: These are not question marks but replacements for Unicode characters that can not be represented in ASCII. Fix the code that produces this string.

Comment: @Tichodroma I'm receiving String from an application which I do not have any control.

Comment: I fear that I'm this case you will not receive any useful data. There must have been something with a meaning where now the replacements are. This will be lost, your data will be corrupt. Fix the source.

Comment: ASCII characters' range is 0-127. This character is at code point 65533, far outside ASCII range.

Comment: How do you receive this string from the other application? Did you do any decoding from a byte array? Code is best.

Comment: You could look at this way: � indicates where characters were removed. That can't be a good thing, especially if you don't know what the characters where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [Unicode code table](http://unicode-table.com/fr/#specials), `&#65533;` (or `\ufffd`) **is** the character �.

You can remove this unicode character from your string with :

```
str = str.replaceAll("&#65533;", "");
```

But you should really try to understand *why* they are there.

Comment: if I try with this, then I am able to remove unwanted characters. `str.replaceAll("&#65533;","");` With `str.replaceAll("\ufffd", "");` it didn't work.

Comment: @user75ponic : I could not test (no access to my dev box). Post edited

Answer (score 1):

```
string.replaceAll("\u0000.*","").replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "");
```

will remove the empty spaces & punctuation marks in the string variable.